Image not loading with Docker
The image loads fine when running the aplication in my machine, but not when running with Docker. What am I doing wrong?
The Image is a image from Bing:
https://www.bing.com/th?id=OHR.FireWave_PT-BR3949258525_1920x1080.jpg&rf=LaDigue_1920x1080.jpg&pid=hp
Here is the Network tab error:
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bing.com%2Fth%3Fid%3DOHR.FireWave_PT-BR3949258525_1920x1080.jpg%26rf%3DLaDigue_1920x1080.jpg%26pid%3Dhp&w=1920&q=75
Request Method:GET
Status Code:400 Bad Request
Remote Address:[::1]:3000
Referrer Policy:strict-origin-when-cross-origin

This is my docker-compose.yml:
version: "3.8"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
      OPENCAGE_API_KEY: ${OPENCAGE_API_KEY}
      OPENWEATHERMAP_API_KEY: ${OPENWEATHERMAP_API_KEY}

And here is my Dockerfile:
FROM node:18-alpine AS builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

FROM node:18-alpine AS runner

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /app/.next ./.next
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json

ENV NODE_ENV=production
ENV OPENCAGE_API_KEY=${OPENCAGE_API_KEY}
ENV OPENWEATHERMAP_API_KEY=${OPENWEATHERMAP_API_KEY}

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]

I feel like the error is in the ports, like it needs something to access bing address. Just don't know what that might be.

What is in your own code, handling that /_next/image URL route?  Can you tell (maybe by adding debug statements) whether this is failing before of after it's making the outbound call?  You shouldn't have to do anything special to allow outbound connections from containers.

I'm actually calling through a API
``https://www.bing.com/HPImageArchive.aspx?format=js&idx=0&n=1&mkt=pt-br`

What component is returning the HTTP 400; is it your own code or the external API?  None of the code in the question obviously makes or handles an HTTP request.

I tried to isolate the problem and created a new NextJS project and run it to see what is going on, the same files I was using i just copied and it worked fine, seems like the problem might be in the libraryif i update it everything should be fine then.

Just confirmed, everything is working as expected the problem was with Axios v1.6.8. When I updated it evereything started to work fine
